# Editing Spreadsheet using Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

After looking for a way to interact Java with google spreadsheet api, I gave up. In the documentation, there is no clear example code for java to use OAuth 2 authentication. My end goal is to edit a spreadsheet using java. I already figured out how to receive data from spreadsheet. If anyone can help, that would be great!
[Java Code Missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkDKA.png)

Link to Spreadsheet API Documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: This is very unclear, which makes it difficult to help. Can you provide an example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the code you have already tried and the error messages you received?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what to code in the first place. The documentation provides sample code for .NET, but there is no code for java. Thanks again.

Comment: If whatever you are using for a language can make an HTTPS GET or POST request, you can create a Stand Alone Apps Script using Content Service, that can act as an intermediary between your App and a Google Spreadsheet.  A Stand Alone Apps Script can be triggered to run over the internet with a GET or POST request.

Comment: Alright, I am using java. I know that java can send GET and POST requests. Now how again would I use this to communicate to Spreadsheets? Thanks.

Comment: Apps Script automatically runs a function named `doGet()` or `doPost()` when the URL to the script is used in the browser.  You can pass information to Apps Script.  With `doGet()` you pass information in the URL's search string.  With a POST request, I think it's part of the payload.  You might also want to ask about OAuth 2 for Java in the Apps Script group.  [Google Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: For my project, however, I am using java, and for the end product, want to merge this code into an app. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: no need for apps script which does simplify the oauth2 part but will give you quota issues. im pretty sure there is a java library that does it, but in any case its like calling any other http api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the library you are looking for. it uses the google gdata library. it's an outdated library but its the only one available and the spreadsheet api is also outdated and the only one that google has made available.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/spreadsheet/package-summary

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I think can be used to help me figure this thing out!